# ArrayDeque class of chars

Tags: java, c++, generics

I'm trying to move a paren balancer I wrote in C++ to Java.

I'm trying to implement the stack with an ArrayDeque class from the Deque interface by declaring an ArrayDeque of characters like so:

`Deque<char> parens = new ArrayDeque<char>();`

and the compiler chokes on it claiming
`expected: reference

found: char`

What am I missing?

Comment: Try this, Deque<Character> parens = new ArrayDeque<Character>();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use primitive types as generic parameters. You need the corresponding Object wrappers:

```
Deque<Character> parens = new ArrayDeque<Character>();
```

> Let's update our Box class to use generics. We'll first create a
>   generic type declaration by changing the code `public class Box` to
>   `public class Box<T>`; this introduces one type variable, named `T`,
>   that can be used anywhere inside the class. This same technique can be
>   applied to interfaces as well. There's nothing particularly complex
>   about this concept. In fact, it's quite similar to what you already
>   know about variables in general. Just think of `T` as a special kind of
>   variable, whose "value" will be whatever type you pass in; this can be
>   any class type, any interface type, or even another type variable. **It
>   just can't be any of the primitive data types.** In this context, we
>   also say that `T` is a formal type parameter of the Box class.
>
> [Source: [Java Tutorial : Generics : Generic Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html)]

See:

- [Java Tutorial: Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)
- [JLS: 4.4 Type Variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108850)
- [JLS: 4.5 Parameterized Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108850)

Comment: I missed a chance by 45 seconds :(. You'r too fast :)

Comment: @krio I know that feeling :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ArrayDeque<Character>` in Java.